# Trying to publish WCF Service with EntityFramework.dll

Tags: wcf, ftp, publish

I wrote a small WCF service to connect to a MySQL database. Locally on my desktop everything works fine. Then I want to publish it to my hostingprovider and everything is transferred correctly except the EntityFramework.dll and the EntityFramework.xml (both max. 1.2 mb). VS 2013 just keeps trying (i think), but nothing happens for a long time. 
I tried several FTP clients (WinSCP, FileZilla) but all of them have the same problem, the .dll and the .xml file are not transferred to the hostingprovider. 
I tried some other filetypes, .pdf, .txt, .jpg, and all of them stopped at 524.288 bytes (512Kb). I could not transfer those files. My hostingprovider says its a problem at my side, not their side.

I am hoping someone has a solution for this problem.

Steven

Comment: Which type of publish do you use? FTP-Deploy? What do you know about FTP server you are trying to use?

Comment: I'm using FTP -deploy, from within VS 2013.